# Unable to add new page to azure devops work item type- Microsoft.VSTS.WorkItemTypes.Bug using azure devops REST API

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-rest-api

I am trying to add custom page to inherited process -> work item type : Bug - Microsoft.VSTS.WorkItemTypes.Bug

Reference MS documentation : *https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/processes/pages/add?view=azure-devops-rest-7.0&tabs=HTTP*

GET process request URL: *https://dev.azure.com/TenantL/_apis/work/processes?api-version=7.0*

[Get process request screen shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4YdQ8.png)

GET Work Item Types for Process URL : https://dev.azure.com/TenantL/_apis/work/processes/6cc6a4ff-e1ea-434d-a6f5-3a21eefeffca/workitemtypes?api-version=7.0

[GET Work Item Types for Process screen shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lYxhJ.png)

POST Request to add Page URI : *https://dev.azure.com/TenantL/_apis/work/processes/6cc6a4ff-e1ea-434d-a6f5-3a21eefeffca/workItemTypes/Microsoft.VSTS.WorkItemTypes.Bug/layout/pages?api-version=7.0*

Request JSON:

```json
{
  "sections": [
    {
      "id": "Section1",
      "groups": [],
      "overridden": false
    }
  ],
  "label": "Page1",
  "order": null,
  "overridden": null,
  "inherited": null,
  "visible": true,
  "locked": false,
  "pageType": 1,
  "contribution": null
}
```

Error Message:

> "VS403115: You cannot modify form layout information for work item types Microsoft.VSTS.WorkItemTypes.Bug in process 6cc6a4ff-e1ea-434d-a6f5-3a21eefeffca as these work item types are locked.",

[image: Error screen shot]

I am trying to add custom page to inherited process -> work item type(Custom/new) : Bug - Microsoft.VSTS.WorkItemTypes.Bug

Comment: Can you try to get the layouts using this `https://dev.azure.com/{Project_name}/_apis/work/processes/{Process_id}/workItemTypes/Microsoft.VSTS.WorkItemTypes.Bug/layout?api-version=5.0-preview.1`, If you are getting the same error like **these work item types are locked.**, then you don't have required permission

Comment: Yes I am getting error like these work item types are locked.
1. can you please tell me what I need to do to get required permission?
2. How I can get required permission?

For below get request I am getting error:

https://dev.azure.com/TenantL/_apis/work/processes/6cc6a4ff-e1ea-434d-a6f5-3a21eefeffca/workItemTypes/Microsoft.VSTS.WorkItemTypes.Bug/layout?api-version=5.0-preview.1

 "message": "VS403115:You cannot modify form layout information for work item types Microsoft.VSTS.WorkItemTypes.Bug in process 6cc6a4ff-e1ea-434d-a6f5-3a21eefeffca as these work item types are locked.",

Comment: Check [this](https://i.imgur.com/obbW8XB.png) in DevOps, if the value is `Not set` then change it to `Allow(Inherited)`

Comment: Thanks for your reply.

It is already Allow(Inherited)

[permission](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y8xoB.png)

Comment: You can't add a page to a **System** work item type like [this](https://i.imgur.com/70qA3kV.png) you are doing, you need create a custom or inherited work item type of that work item type like [this](https://i.imgur.com/0GwFQt8.png) and then add page to that work item type. 
Refer https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/how-to-add-a-field-to-work-item-type-using-api/566750, its says **System** work item types are un-editable.

You can only add pages either to [this](https://i.imgur.com/VooU8w1.png) or [this](https://i.imgur.com/2jDvhKw.png) work item types

Answer (score 0):

> "VS403115: You cannot modify form layout information for work item types Microsoft.VSTS.WorkItemTypes.Bug in process 6cc6a4ff-e1ea-434d-a6f5-3a21eefeffca as these work item types are locked."

By looking at the screenshot shared by you, it seems like you are trying to create a layout page in `Microsoft.VSTS.WorkItemTypes.Bug` work item type.

You can't create a layout page in a System generated work item type(Microsoft.VSTS.WorkItemTypes.Bug), as it is un-editable. Refer this [link](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/how-to-add-a-field-to-work-item-type-using-api/566750).

In order to create a layout page of Microsoft.VSTS.WorkItemTypes.Bug work item type or any System generated type, you need to create a custom or inherited work item type of any System generated type using below URL-

*URL-*

```
POST https://dev.azure.com/{Project_name}/_apis/work/processes/_apis/work/processes/{Process_id}/workitemtypes?api-version=7.0
```

*Its an inherited work item type*

[image]

For custom work item type, set **`inheritsFrom: null`** in your request body.

You can only add pages to the below Work item types, as `"customization": "system"` is un-editable

[image]

[image]

*You can get these details using below URL-*

```
GET https://dev.azure.com/{Project_name}/_apis/work/processes/_apis/work/processes/{Process_id}/workitemtypes?api-version=7.0
```